# Add multiple plugin directories

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory

## The task

You can register add additional Themes directories using `register_theme_directory()` for your WP installation. Sadly core doesn't deliver with the same functionality for plugins. We already have MU-Plugin, Drop-Ins, Plugins and Themes. But we need more for a better file organization.

#### Here's the list of tasks to achieve:

- Add an additional plugin directory
- For each plugin directory, a new "tab" is needed as shown here <sup>[1]</sup>
- The additional directory would've the same functionality as the default plugin directory has

## What's in there for you?

The best and most complete answer will be awarded a bounty.

---

<sup>[1] Additional tab for a new plugin folder/directory</sup>
[image]

Comment: Since directory structure is pretty tied to directory constants I have doubts that doing this on file system level is practical (without core adoption that is). Virtual layer of organization in admin might be easier to achieve on extension level.

Comment: @Rarst Which shouldn't hold _you_ back from adding your thoughts :)

Comment: This would be a great feature.

Comment: Feature sounds good. Just need to reverse engineer core, figure out how it should be done (the WP way) and then submit a patch to the Devs...you'd want to look at register_theme_directory() - search_theme_directories() - get_raw_theme_root() - get_theme_roots() - get_theme() - get_themes()

Comment: Also: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=register_plugin_directory - You really should submit this to the Trac ticket list, so it can get some recognition.

Comment: Guys: Submit _what_? This is a question, not an answer with full blown code :) FYI: [A new ticket on trac to rewrite `get_themes()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20103) to a class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okay, I'll take a stab at this. Some limitations I encountered along the way:

1. There are not a lot of filters in subclasses of WP_List_Table, at
   least no where we need them to be.
2. Due to that lack of filters, we can't really maintain an accurate
   list of plugin types at the top.
3. We also have to use some awesome (read: dirty) JavaScript hacks to
   display plugins as active.

I wrapped my admin area code inside a class, so my function names are not prefixed. You can see all of this code [here](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WP-Plugin-Directories). Please contribute!

**Central API**

Just a simple function that sets up a global variable which will contain our plugin directories in an associative array.  The `$key` is going to be something used internally to fetch plugins, etc. `$dir` is either a full path or something relative to the `wp-content` directory.  `$label` is going to be for our display in the admin area (eg. a translatable string).

```
<?php
function register_plugin_directory( $key, $dir, $label )
{
    global $wp_plugin_directories;
    if( empty( $wp_plugin_directories ) ) $wp_plugin_directories = array();

    if( ! file_exists( $dir ) && file_exists( trailingslashit( WP_CONTENT_DIR ) . $dir ) )
    {
        $dir = trailingslashit( WP_CONTENT_DIR ) . $dir;
    }

    $wp_plugin_directories[$key] = array(
        'label' => $label,
        'dir'   => $dir
    );
}
```

Then, of course, we need to load the plugins.  Hook into `plugins_loaded` way late and go through the active plugins, loading each.

**Admin Area**

Let's set up our functionality inside a class.

```
<?php
class CD_APD_Admin
{

    /**
     * The container for all of our custom plugins
     */
    protected $plugins = array();

    /**
     * What custom actions are we allowed to handle here?
     */
    protected $actions = array();

    /**
     * The original count of the plugins
     */
    protected $all_count = 0;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @since 0.1
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'load-plugins.php', array( &$this, 'init' ) );
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( &$this, 'setup_actions' ), 1 );

    }

} // end class
```

We're going to hook into `plugins_loaded` really early and set up the allowed "actions" we'll be using.  These will handle plugin activation and deactivation as the built in functions can't do it with custom directories.

```
function setup_actions()
{
    $tmp = array(
        'custom_activate',
        'custom_deactivate'
    );
    $this->actions = apply_filters( 'custom_plugin_actions', $tmp );
}
```

Then there's the function hooked into `load-plugins.php`.  This does all sorts of fun stuff.

```
function init()
{
    global $wp_plugin_directories;

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    $this->get_plugins();

    $this->handle_actions();

    add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views' ) );

    // check to see if we're using one of our custom directories
    if( $this->get_plugin_status() )
    {
        add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views_again' ) );
        add_filter( 'all_plugins', array( &$this, 'filter_plugins' ) );
        // TODO: support bulk actions
        add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . $screen->id, '__return_empty_array' );
        add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', array( &$this, 'action_links' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'scripts' ) );
    }
}
```

Let's go through that one thing at a time.  the `get_plugins` method, is a wrapper around another function. It fills the attribute `plugins` with data.

```
function get_plugins()
{
    global $wp_plugin_directories;
    foreach( array_keys( $wp_plugin_directories ) as $key )
    {
       $this->plugins[$key] = cd_apd_get_plugins( $key );
    }
}
```

`cd_apd_get_plugins` is a rip of of the built in `get_plugins` function without the hardcoded `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `plugins` business.  Basically: get the directory from the `$wp_plugin_directories` global, open it, find all the plugin files.  Store them in the cache for later.

```
<?php
function cd_apd_get_plugins( $dir_key ) 
{
    global $wp_plugin_directories;

    // invalid dir key? bail
    if( ! isset( $wp_plugin_directories[$dir_key] ) )
    {
        return array();
    }
    else
    {
        $plugin_root = $wp_plugin_directories[$dir_key]['dir'];
    }

    if ( ! $cache_plugins = wp_cache_get( 'plugins', 'plugins') )
        $cache_plugins = array();

    if ( isset( $cache_plugins[$dir_key] ) )
        return $cache_plugins[$dir_key];

    $wp_plugins = array();

    $plugins_dir = @ opendir( $plugin_root );
    $plugin_files = array();
    if ( $plugins_dir ) {
        while ( ( $file = readdir( $plugins_dir ) ) !== false ) {
            if ( substr($file, 0, 1) == '.' )
                continue;
            if ( is_dir( $plugin_root.'/'.$file ) ) {
                $plugins_subdir = @ opendir( $plugin_root.'/'.$file );
                if ( $plugins_subdir ) {
                    while (($subfile = readdir( $plugins_subdir ) ) !== false ) {
                        if ( substr($subfile, 0, 1) == '.' )
                            continue;
                        if ( substr($subfile, -4) == '.php' )
                            $plugin_files[] = "$file/$subfile";
                    }
                    closedir( $plugins_subdir );
                }
            } else {
                if ( substr($file, -4) == '.php' )
                    $plugin_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir( $plugins_dir );
    }

    if ( empty($plugin_files) )
        return $wp_plugins;

    foreach ( $plugin_files as $plugin_file ) {
        if ( !is_readable( "$plugin_root/$plugin_file" ) )
            continue;

        $plugin_data = get_plugin_data( "$plugin_root/$plugin_file", false, false ); //Do not apply markup/translate as it'll be cached.

        if ( empty ( $plugin_data['Name'] ) )
            continue;

        $wp_plugins[trim( $plugin_file )] = $plugin_data;
    }

    uasort( $wp_plugins, '_sort_uname_callback' );

    $cache_plugins[$dir_key] = $wp_plugins;
    wp_cache_set('plugins', $cache_plugins, 'plugins');

    return $wp_plugins;
}
```

Next up is the pesky business of actually activating and deactivating plugins.  To do this, we use the `handle_actions` method.  This is, again, blatantly ripped off from the top of the core `wp-admin/plugins.php` file.

```
function handle_actions()
{
    $action = isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

    // not allowed to handle this action? bail.
    if( ! in_array( $action, $this->actions ) ) return;

    // Get the plugin we're going to activate
    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : false;
    if( ! $plugin ) return;

    $context = $this->get_plugin_status();

    switch( $action )
    {
        case 'custom_activate':
            if( ! current_user_can('activate_plugins') )
                    wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to manage plugins for this site.') );

            check_admin_referer( 'custom_activate-' . $plugin );

            $result = cd_apd_activate_plugin( $plugin, $context );
            if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) 
            {
                if ( 'unexpected_output' == $result->get_error_code() ) 
                {
                    $redirect = add_query_arg( 'plugin_status', $context, self_admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) );
                    wp_redirect( add_query_arg( '_error_nonce', wp_create_nonce( 'plugin-activation-error_' . $plugin ), $redirect ) ) ;
                    exit();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    wp_die( $result );
                }
            }

            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'plugin_status' => $context, 'activate' => 'true' ), self_admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) ) );
            exit();
            break;
        case 'custom_deactivate':
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
                wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to deactivate plugins for this site.') );

            check_admin_referer('custom_deactivate-' . $plugin);
            cd_apd_deactivate_plugins( $plugin, $context );
            if ( headers_sent() )
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='" . esc_attr( "0;url=plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=$status&paged=$page&s=$s" ) . "' />";
            else
                wp_redirect( self_admin_url("plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=$context") );
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            do_action( 'custom_plugin_dir_' . $action );
            break;
    }

}
```

A couple custom functions here again. `cd_apd_activate_plugin` (ripped off from `activate_plugin`) and `cd_apd_deactivate_plugins` (ripped off from `deactivate_plugins`).  Both are the same as their respective "parent" functions without the hard coded directories.

```
function cd_apd_activate_plugin( $plugin, $context, $silent = false ) 
{
    $plugin = trim( $plugin );

    $redirect = add_query_arg( 'plugin_status', $context, admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) );
    $redirect = apply_filters( 'custom_plugin_redirect', $redirect );

    $current = get_option( 'active_plugins_' . $context, array() );

    $valid = cd_apd_validate_plugin( $plugin, $context );
    if ( is_wp_error( $valid ) )
        return $valid;

    if ( !in_array($plugin, $current) ) {
        if ( !empty($redirect) )
            wp_redirect(add_query_arg('_error_nonce', wp_create_nonce('plugin-activation-error_' . $plugin), $redirect)); // we'll override this later if the plugin can be included without fatal error
        ob_start();
        include_once( $valid );

        if ( ! $silent ) {
            do_action( 'custom_activate_plugin', $plugin, $context );
            do_action( 'custom_activate_' . $plugin, $context );
        }

        $current[] = $plugin;
        sort( $current );
        update_option( 'active_plugins_' . $context, $current );

        if ( ! $silent ) {
            do_action( 'custom_activated_plugin', $plugin, $context );
        }

        if ( ob_get_length() > 0 ) {
            $output = ob_get_clean();
            return new WP_Error('unexpected_output', __('The plugin generated unexpected output.'), $output);
        }
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the deactivation function

```
function cd_apd_deactivate_plugins( $plugins, $context, $silent = false ) {
    $current = get_option( 'active_plugins_' . $context, array() );

    foreach ( (array) $plugins as $plugin ) 
    {
        $plugin = trim( $plugin );
        if ( ! in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) continue;

        if ( ! $silent )
            do_action( 'custom_deactivate_plugin', $plugin, $context );

        $key = array_search( $plugin, $current );
        if ( false !== $key ) {
            array_splice( $current, $key, 1 );
        }

        if ( ! $silent ) {
            do_action( 'custom_deactivate_' . $plugin, $context );
            do_action( 'custom_deactivated_plugin', $plugin, $context );
        }
    }

    update_option( 'active_plugins_' . $context, $current );
}
```

There's also `cd_apd_validate_plugin` function, which off course, is a rip off of `validate_plugin` without the hard coded junk.

```
<?php
function cd_apd_validate_plugin( $plugin, $context ) 
{
    $rv = true;
    if ( validate_file( $plugin ) )
    {
        $rv = new WP_Error('plugin_invalid', __('Invalid plugin path.'));
    }

    global $wp_plugin_directories;
    if( ! isset( $wp_plugin_directories[$context] ) )
    {
        $rv = new WP_Error( 'invalid_context', __( 'The context for this plugin does not exist' ) );
    }

    $dir = $wp_plugin_directories[$context]['dir'];
    if( ! file_exists( $dir . '/' . $plugin) )
    {
        $rv = new WP_Error( 'plugin_not_found', __( 'Plugin file does not exist.' ) );
    }

    $installed_plugins = cd_apd_get_plugins( $context );
    if ( ! isset($installed_plugins[$plugin]) )
    {
        $rv = new WP_Error( 'no_plugin_header', __('The plugin does not have a valid header.') );
    }

    $rv = $dir . '/' . $plugin;
    return $rv;
}
```

Alright, with that out of the way.  We can actually start talking about the **list table display**

Step 1: add our views to the list at the top of the table. This is done by filtering `views_{$screen->id}` inside our `init` function.

```
add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views' ) );
```

Then the actual hooked function just loops through the `$wp_plugin_directories`.  If one of the newly registered directories has plugins, we'll include it in the display.

```
function views( $views )
{
    global $wp_plugin_directories;

    // bail if we don't have any extra dirs
    if( empty( $wp_plugin_directories ) ) return $views;

    // Add our directories to the action links
    foreach( $wp_plugin_directories as $key => $info )
    {
        if( ! count( $this->plugins[$key] ) ) continue;
        $class = $this->get_plugin_status() == $key ? ' class="current" ' : '';
        $views[$key] = sprintf( 
            '<a href="%s"' . $class . '>%s <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>',
            add_query_arg( 'plugin_status', $key, 'plugins.php' ),
            esc_html( $info['label'] ),
            count( $this->plugins[$key] )
        );
    }
    return $views;
}
```

The first thing we need to do if we happen to be viewing a custom plugin directory page is filter the views again.  We need to get rid of the `inactive` count because it's not going to be accurate.  A consequence of there being no filters where we need them to be. Hook in again...

```
if( $this->get_plugin_status() )
{
    add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views_again' ) );
}
```

And a quick unset...

```
function views_again( $views )
{
    if( isset( $views['inactive'] ) ) unset( $views['inactive'] );
    return $views;
}
```

Next up, let's get rid of the plugins you would have otherwise seen in the list table, and replace them with our custom plugins.  Hook into `all_plugins`.

```
if( $this->get_plugin_status() )
{
    add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views_again' ) );
    add_filter( 'all_plugins', array( &$this, 'filter_plugins' ) );
}
```

Since we already set up our plugins and data (see `setup_plugins` above) , the `filter_plugins` method just (1) saves the count on all the plugins for later, and (2) replaces the plugins in the list table.

```
function filter_plugins( $plugins )
{
    if( $key = $this->get_plugin_status() )
    {
        $this->all_count = count( $plugins );
        $plugins = $this->plugins[$key];
    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

And now we'll kill the bulk actions.  These could easily be supported, I suppose?

```
if( $this->get_plugin_status() )
{
    add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views_again' ) );
    add_filter( 'all_plugins', array( &$this, 'filter_plugins' ) );
    // TODO: support bulk actions
    add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . $screen->id, '__return_empty_array' );
}
```

The default plugin actions links are not going to work for us.  So instead, we need to set up our own (with the custom actions, etc). In the `init` function.

```
if( $this->get_plugin_status() )
{
    add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views_again' ) );
    add_filter( 'all_plugins', array( &$this, 'filter_plugins' ) );
    // TODO: support bulk actions
    add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . $screen->id, '__return_empty_array' );
    add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', array( &$this, 'action_links' ), 10, 2 );
}
```

The only things that get changed here are (1) we're changing the actions, (2) keeping the plugin status in, and (3) changing the nonce names a bit.

```
function action_links( $links, $plugin_file )
{
    $context = $this->get_plugin_status();

    // let's just start over
    $links = array();
    $links['activate'] = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" title="Activate this plugin">%s</a>',
        wp_nonce_url( 'plugins.php?action=custom_activate&amp;plugin=' . $plugin_file . '&amp;plugin_status=' . esc_attr( $context ), 'custom_activate-' . $plugin_file ),
        __( 'Activate' )
    );

    $active = get_option( 'active_plugins_' . $context, array() );
    if( in_array( $plugin_file, $active ) )
    {
        $links['deactivate'] = sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" title="Deactivate this plugin" class="cd-apd-deactivate">%s</a>',
            wp_nonce_url( 'plugins.php?action=custom_deactivate&amp;plugin=' . $plugin_file . '&amp;plugin_status=' . esc_attr( $context ), 'custom_deactivate-' . $plugin_file ),
            __( 'Deactivate' )
        );
    }
    return $links;
}
```

And finally, we just need to enqueue some JavaScript to top it off.  In the `init` function again (all together this time).

```
if( $this->get_plugin_status() )
{
    add_filter( 'views_' . $screen->id, array( &$this, 'views_again' ) );
    add_filter( 'all_plugins', array( &$this, 'filter_plugins' ) );
    // TODO: support bulk actions
    add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . $screen->id, '__return_empty_array' );
    add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', array( &$this, 'action_links' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'scripts' ) );
}
```

While enqueueing ourJS, we'll also use `wp_localize_script` to get the value of the total "all plugins" count.

```
function scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'cd-apd-js',
        CD_APD_URL . 'js/apd.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        null
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'cd-apd-js',
        'cd_apd',
        array(
            'count' => esc_js( $this->all_count )
        )
    );
}
```

And of course, the JS is just some nice hacks to get the list table active/inactive plugins to display properly.  We'll also stick the correct count of all plugins back into the `All` link.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('li.all a').removeClass('current').find('span.count').html('(' + cd_apd.count + ')');
    jQuery('.wp-list-table.plugins tr').each(function(){
        var is_active = jQuery(this).find('a.cd-apd-deactivate');
        if(is_active.length) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
            jQuery(this).find('div.plugin-version-author-uri').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

**Wrap Up**

The actual loading of additional plugin directories is pretty unexciting.  Getting the list table to display correctly is the more difficult part. I'm still not completely satisfied with how it turned out, but maybe someone can [improve the code](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WP-Plugin-Directories)

Comment: Impressive! Really good work. I’ll take some time over the weekend to study your code. Note: There is a function `__return_empty_array()`.

Comment: Thanks!  Feedback is always welcome.  Incorporated the `__return_empty_array` function!

Comment: You should collect a list of all places where a simple core filter would have saved you a separate function. And then … submit a Trac ticket.

Comment: This is really great. It would be even cooler if we could this as a library inside a Theme (see my comment on Github: https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WP-Plugin-Directories/issues/4)

Comment: +1 Can't believed I'd missed this answer - great work! I shall look over your code in more detail over the weekend :). @Julien_c - why would you use this inside a theme?

Comment: @StephenHarris Please see my use case here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/plugin-or-theme-containing-its-own-plugins

Comment: The bounty will be awarded in 23 hours.

Answer (score 4):

I don't personally have any interest in modifying the UI, but I'd love a more organized file system layout, for several reasons.

To that end, another approach would be to use symlinks.

```
wp-content
    |-- plugins
        |-- acme-widgets               -> ../plugins-custom/acme-widgets
        |-- acme-custom-post-types     -> ../plugins-custom/acme-custom-post-types
        |-- acme-business-logic        -> ../plugins-custom/acme-business-logic
        |-- google-authenticator       -> ../plugins-external/google-authenticator
        |-- rest-api                   -> ../plugins-external/rest-api
        |-- quick-navigation-interface -> ../plugins-external/quick-navigation-interface
    |-- plugins-custom
        |-- acme-widgets
        |-- acme-custom-post-types
        |-- acme-business-logic
    |-- plugins-external
        |-- google-authenticator
        |-- rest-api
        |-- quick-navigation-interface
```

You could setup your custom plugins in `plugins-custom`, which could be part of your project's version control repository.

Then you could install 3rd-party dependencies into `plugins-external` (via Composer, or Git submodules, or whatever you prefer).

Then you could have a simple Bash script or WP-CLI command that scans the additional directories, and creates a symlink in `plugins` for each subfolder it finds.

`plugins` would still be cluttered, but it wouldn't matter because you'd only need to interact with `plugins-custom` and `plugins-external`.

Scaling to `n` extra directories would follow the same process as the first two.

Answer (score -3):

Or you could also use COMPOSER with custom directory path setted to point to wp-content folder. If it is not a direct answer of your question is a new way of thinking wordpress, move on to composer before it eats you up.

Comment: Done moving to Composer a long time ago. Please look up the date of this question. Aside from that: This is not really a answer. Maybe show how to actually set this up?