# Having separate plugins and themes folder for multi-site setup

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, multisite

My multi-site setup uses sub-directory.  I am creating one plugin + one theme to customize each of the sites. Is there any way to have separate plugins and themes folder per site like so or something similar:

```
root
+----wp-content
|     +----site1
|          +----plugins
|          +----themes
|     +----site2
|          +----plugins
|          +----themes
+----mu-plugins
|     +----shared-plugin1
|     +----shared-plugin2
+----plugins
|     +----optional-plugin1
|     +----optional-plugin2
```

The goal is so that each site can only activate/deactivate the plugin/theme intended for it.

**Edit**

[Multisite Plugin Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-plugin-manager/) can be a way to achieve what I want to do logically, though it does not put the plugins in their individual directories.  I am still interested to hear other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`register_theme_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_theme_directory) to ... well register additional theme directories.

For plugins, we don't know how to get around it (so far). If you want, then you [can jump into the discussion here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43262/add-multiple-plugin-directories) and add your thought, share your try-outs and maybe we all together will come to an solution :)

Comment: Thanks, this points me to the right direction.  I will my hands on creating a register_plugin_directory()